# SQL Developer debugger not stepping into in anonymous block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to debug an anonymous code block in PLSQL.

```
DECLARE
    l_pls   PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    NULL;
    l_pls := 2222222222;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
        dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
```

However, when pressing CTRL+SHIFT+F10 (after having selected the step into option in tools-preferences-debugger), the debugger does not stop at the first line an wait, but executes the block.

```
Connecting to the database RBIP.
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( 'XX.XX.XX.XX', 'XXXXX' )
Debugger accepted connection from database on port XXXXX.
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.DISCONNECT()
ORA-06512: at line 5
ORA-01426: numeric overflow
ORA-01426: numeric overflow
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database RBIP.
Debugger disconnected from database.
```

How can I get the debugger to work?

Comment: I believe in SQL Developer you have to set a breakpoint first. In PL/SQL Developer which you also tagged, it behaves as you expected.

Answer (score -1):

The error is

> ORA-01426: numeric overflow

Maximum value of [`PLS_INTEGER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-9517B7AC-9CEA-4C36-A454-52588BEEBE8F) data type is 2,147,483,647 (2^31 – 1).

Use [`NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78) data type.